# Ubuntu 20.04 Ethernet connection not running at full speed

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

My ethernet port is capable of 1Gbps but it is being limited to 100Mbps. My router has 4 Gigabit LAN connections and my ubuntu machine is connected to one of them. I'd like utilize the full speed as this is a media server and it's taking a long time to transfer information from my personal computer to the server. Here's some information:

```
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
     logical name: enp11s0
     version: 03
     serial: 70:85:c2:3e:88:8c
     size: 100Mbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 ip=192.168.1.143 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
     resources: irq:34 memory:fe000000-fe01ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fe020000-fe023fff
```

```
Settings for enp11s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

I tried doing the auto-recognition again but the result did change. Furthermore, this is a custom build and unfortunately, ASRock doesn't have official support for any OS other than Windows and therefore there are no drivers for me to download and install. However, I noticed when looking at the specs of my motherboard, that the ethernet controller is the Intel I211AT. I downloaded and installed the Linux drivers but nothing changed. Furthermore, when trying to update any driver at all by going in Additional Drivers, there are never any drivers for me to download and install and I'm therefore stuck with the automatic drivers that were installed automatically. What can I do to fix my ethernet port other than getting a PCIe card or usb dongle? What can I do install any missing or outdated drivers? It's my first time having Ubuntu on bare metal instead of a VM and any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

PS driver-wise, I have an old AMD Radeon HD7850 card as I simply needed something to display video and nothing else. I think it's going to be hard to find any drivers for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: More than likely a cable problem, or a port problem on the router. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Describe your cabling from the computer to the router/modem.

Comment: It's not a cable issue as I'm using the same Cat 5e cable I was using previously, connected to the same port on my router. Furthermore, I'm sure that the cable connection is fine since I crimped the cable myself. As for the cable itself, it's around 5 meters of cat5e cable. I tried changing the ethernet port on my router, disconnected everything else connected to it, but nothing worked

Comment: Do you have a standard pre-made cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cable you can try? Not a cable that you made.

Comment: @heynnema so sorry I never noticed the notification for your reply. Turns out you were right, it was a cable issue, one of the connectors wasn't connected properly. I've replaced the bad connector and I'm now getting a  full 1Gb/s. Sorry about replying so late but you've been very helpful!. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

It was a bad cat 5e cable. Replaced it. Everything is working now.